# Mysqli prepared statement (SQL injection prevention)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, code-injection

after stopping the use of deprecated mysql_* functions, I switched to mysqli. But then, I noticed that non-prepared statements are non-secure against SQL injection. Then, I changed again my code.

What I had was the following function that checks if the variable **$ID** exists in the database and prints the value of **title** for that row:

```
function showPostTitle($ID, $mysqli) {
    $result = $mysqli -> query("SELECT ID, title FROM blog where ID = $ID");
    $row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
    echo $row['title'];
}
```

I changed it to this:

```
function showPostTitle($ID, $mysqli) {
    $stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT ID, title FROM blog WHERE ID = ?");
    $stmt -> bind_param("i", $ID);
    $stmt -> execute();
    $stmt -> bind_result($ID, $title);
    $stmt -> fetch();
    print_r($title);
    $stmt -> free_result();
}
```

My question is: is this the correct way to implement prepared statements? Plus, am I safe now from SQL Injections? Big thanks to whoever will answer this question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mysqli logic seems fine, there are some examples in the [PHP manual here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in case you have not seen them.

Why are you selecting the ID when not consuming it though? Also you don't really need to bind a result when it's only going to have one row returned in the full result set as I assume will happen in this case (ID is unique index in the table), use [get_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) instead.

Using mysqli prepare will protect against all the common injection attacks but not 0-day style stuff which hasn't made it to the driver yet.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I was also selecting $ID without using it as you said :) I removed it!

Comment: Isn't using PDO or mysqli really just a matter of opinion and if there is ever any plans to change from mySQL to something else?  If the person is getting away from mysql_ let them use what is easier for them.

Comment: I tought that both PDO and mysqli were almost the same to do what I need. Am I wrong?

Comment: PDO is more future proof, PDO allows you to easily swap out your mysql DB for another type, easily. That's the main difference but also has many more options than mysqli and has no procedural alternatives which helps enforce an oo style. Additionally mysqli may become deprecated where PDO will not.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this post:

[Are PDO prepared statements sufficient to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection)

It's using PDO instead of MySQLi, which is solving the same problem by creating prepared statements.

Sorry for not answering your question, but just wanted to provide a resource for you to consider.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a read, in the while, I hope that someone can check my code and tell me if (apart from the SQL injection question) it is implemented correctly.