# MySQL UPDATE query problems

Tags: php, mysql

I have a super easy question. I have a form that echoes out a mySQL record that the user can update. I make my changes, and it tells me that the update is successful, but when I look at the table, the changes do not go through. What is the problem here?

This is the first script.

```
<?php
require_once("models/config.php");
?>

<table border=1>
 <tr>
<td align=center>Edit Form</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
  <table>
  <?
  $personid=$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

  $order = "SELECT * FROM persons where personid='$personid'";

  $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$order);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  ?>
  <form method="post" action="edit_data.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<? echo "$row[personid]"?>"> 
  <tr>Person ID:<? echo "$row[personid]"?></tr>
    <tr>        
      <td>First Name</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" 
    size="20" value="<? echo "$row[firstname]"?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Surname</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="surname" size="40" 
      value="<? echo "$row[surname]"?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">
        <input type="submit" 
      name="submit value" value="Edit">
      </td>
    </tr>
     </form>
    </table>
    </td>
 </tr>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Which then goes through to this:

```
<?
require_once("models/config.php");

 $personid = $_POST['personid'];
 $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, htmlspecialchars($_POST['firstname']));
 $surname = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, htmlspecialchars($_POST['surname']));

 $order = "UPDATE persons SET firstname='$firstname', surname='$surname' WHERE   personid='$personid'";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$order);
 if (!$result) {
echo "Error entering data! <BR>";
echo mysql_error();
} else {
echo "User updated to $firstname $surname <BR>";
}
?>
```

Is there something I am missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried looking at the output of `mysqli_error()`?

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). and are using `mysql_error()` (the one WITHOUT an `i`), instead of `mysqli_error()` (**WITH** an `i`).

Comment: Your HTML input is named `name="id"` but your PHP references `$_POST['personid']`.

Comment: Mix of `mysqli_*` and `mysql_*` functions for one thing `echo mysql_error();` so that won't help you. Change it to `echo mysqli_error($mysqli);` and it will tell you what's "not" going on.

Comment: I don't get any output for 'mysqli_error()'. I get a success message.

Comment: You are not validating your inputs at all. If you were, you would have noticed that you are sending a bad value to the database.

Comment: Use `mysqli_error($mysqli);` and not just `mysqli_error();` @JLA

Comment: Also, I strongly suggest that you use parameterized queries instead of string escapes.

Comment: Problem solved. Yes, it was that my input was named "id" and PHP was referencing "personid". 

I thought string escapes were good enough but obviously not - I'll defer to your advice. I'll give the prepared statements and parameterized queries a try - hopefully I'll get it right.

Comment: Hi, @Nate C-K I've revised the script to include prepared statements and pasted it as an answer to my own question. Would you mind taking a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending a hidden input named `id` and trying to use a `$_POST['personid']`
correct that

You may also pay attention to the comments you had (SQL Injection's one at least)

Comment: Hi, yes - that was the exact problem! As I said in the comments above, I thought that the htmlspecialchars command and escape_string was enough.

I'll be giving it a try and hopefully I;ll get some functioning code.

Comment: Hi, @Olvathar I've revised the script to include prepared statements and pasted it as an answer to my own question. Would you mind taking a look?

Answer (score 0):

Your form sends the id in the field `id`, while you refer to it as `personid`.

The reason why this appears to be working, is that the update in itself is correct. `$personid` is treated as an empty string, so the update correctly updates all records that have an empty `personid`, which is no record at all.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so here is a revised script with prepared statements. The script is working in the sense that updates are being made to the records. Two questions:
1) is this safe from My-SQL injections?
2) This is updating records successfully, but now it is echoing out "Error entering data!", how come?

```
<?
require_once("models/config.php");

$personid = $_POST['personid'];
$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, htmlspecialchars($_POST['firstname']));
$surname = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, htmlspecialchars($_POST['surname']));

$order = "UPDATE persons SET firstname=?, surname=? WHERE personid=?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $order);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssi", $_POST['firstname'], $_POST['surname'],   $_POST['personid']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); 


$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$stmt);
if (!$result) {
echo "Error entering data! <BR>";
echo mysqli_error($mysqli);
} else {
echo "User updated to $firstname $surname <BR>";
}
?>
```

I'm sure the second question is a rather boneheaded one - do I just reverse the conditions?

Comment: On failure, mysqli_query returns `FALSE` (so `$result === false`). On success, it returns the number of rows updated. What you are doing treats 0 and `FALSE` the same way. It will help you debug if you treat them differently. I suggest you also print the parameter values in your script output to help you be sure you're really sending the database the values that you think you're sending.

Comment: putting in to '$result === false' works. Is the script OK in terms of SQL injection vulnerability?

Comment: First to say is that mysqli_stmt_execute() DO execute the query, you don't need `mysql_query($mysqli,$stmt);` line, you'll just update the line twice
About SQL injection you can read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14199690/mysqli-prepared-statement-sql-injection-prevention that prepared statements are strong against SQL injection
Perhaps you will also find usefull check `mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt)` if you want to know if any row was affected