# php - combobox not indexed

Tags: php, combobox

i want to ask why my combobox not indexed?

here is a code

```
<form method="post" action="../php/proses-list-maintenance.php">
    <p style="font-size:15px; font-family:Coda; color:black;">Pilih Aplikasi :</p>
    <select name="comboapp" class="form-control">
        <?php foreach ($list_app as $app) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $app['application_id'] ?>"><?php echo $app['application_name'] ?></option>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Pilih</button>                 
</form>
```

and here is action code

```
include '../koneksi.php';

$id = $_POST['comboapp'];
$query = "select * from application where application_id = '$id'";
$hasil = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$data_app = mysqli_fetch_assoc($hasil);

$query2 = "SELECT * FROM maintenance where maintenance_id = '$id'";
$hasil2 = mysqli_query($db, $query2);

if ($hasil == true && $hasil2 == true) {
    echo "<script>location.href='../admin/list-maintenance.php?aaa='+$id</script>";
    $data_app = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($hasil)) {
        $data_app[] = $row; 
    }
    $data_man = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($hasil2)) {
        $data_man[] = $row; 
    }
}
```

and when I run, I got this notice

```
undefined index: comboapp
```

when the combo box is selected and the button is clicked. I want the data id's in the combo box enter the data into $id

Comment: Have you done a `var_dump($_POST);` in `../php/proses-list-maintenance.php` to see what is contained in `$_POST`?

Comment: so, basically you get error on `$id = $_POST['comboapp'];` ? what does `var_dump($_POST)` gave you? (put the code before `$id=$_POST[...`

Comment: A piece of advise, don't use post data directly in your sql query, you will be left vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14199690/mysqli-prepared-statement-sql-injection-prevention

Comment: what is `$list_app` for? so some more code where you set value of `$list_app`

Comment: One more mistake is, mysqli_query won't return true for select query. Check this http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve